# Jenkins: Trigger a future build once a job is completed

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, hudson

I can't seem to find the best way to do that.

I have a Jenkins job I ran manually (say a job that creates a temporary file somewhere).

I want to be able to clean this up (e.g. delete the temporary file) after 2-3 hours.

I was thinking adding a Post Deploy action that will run a job with some parameters + some delay. But I can't find anything like that.

I've noticed several schedule plugins or REST API options, but nothing that as simple as "When Succesfully Building A, Build B in X minutes".

Suggestions?

Suggestions?

Comment: Why do you need to wait after job A? Can't you do the cleanup as soon as job A is done?

Comment: @Moberg This was simply the requirement :) something needs to happen 3 hours after some other job execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could exploit the `Quiet period`.

job1 -> (sleep -> fake-job) -> job2

so let job1 trigger the fake-job whch has a quiet period of 7200 seconds and this fake-job will trigger your cleanup job.

Comment: Thanks. This works, with tons of limitations though... I wish there was a nicer dedicated plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Parameterized Trigger Plugin (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin).
Here you can pass predefined parameter to Project to build like sleep_time parameter and you can handle it in triggered Jenkins job. Also you can configure Trigger build on Stable / Unstable / always trigger conditions.

I hope it will be useful for you.

Comment: Are you suggesting to pass in a manual sleep_time argument and manage that in some code in the job itself? that would mean a job blocked, so not very natural to what I'm after.